# Volver a ejecutar un bucle while

Tags: python, bucles, while

Tengo el siguiente código (no está completo, solo pongo las partes de interés) en Python para crear un bingo.

```
# Método para el control de volver a jugar otra partida de Bingo.

def JugarDeNuevo(self):
    j = input("¿Quieres volver a jugar? Responde si/no: ")
    if (j == "si"):
        return True
    elif (j == "no"):
        return False
    else:
        input("Por favor, introduce un valor válido: ")

# Método para la implementación de la lógica del juego de Bingo. Implementación de LINEA y BINGO.

def Juego(self):
    ....
    juegoActivo = True
    while (juegoActivo):
        ....

    hayJuego = self.JugarDeNuevo()
    if hayJuego == True:
        print("Volvemos a jugar.")
        juegoActivo = True
    else:
        print("Adios " + nombre + ".¡¡¡Vuelve pronto!!!")

juego = Bingo()
print(juego.Juego())
```

Necesito que cuando la respuesta a la pregunta ¿quieres volver a jugar? sea un si vuelva al bucle `while` que inicia el juego, pero no lo consigo. No consigo ver si hay algo incorrecto.

Comment: En mi opinión, en el while debería estar la pregunta al jugador, y que esta, al ser sí, llamase al comportamiento del juego. Es decir, pregunta al jugador, ejecutas juego, preguntas al jugador, ejecutas juego, hasta que este te diga que no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltan dos ciclos `while`, uno que envuelva al ciclo de juego y otro en `JugarDeNuevo` por si el usuario ingresa algo que no debe:

```
class Bingo:
    def jugar_de_nuevo(self):
        j = input("¿Quieres volver a jugar? Responde si/no: ")
        while True:
            if (j == "si"):
                return True
            elif (j == "no"):
                return False
            else:
                j = input("Por favor, introduce un valor válido: ")

    def jugar(self):
        while True:
            juego_activo = True
            while juego_activo:
                print("Jugando")
                print("Terminó el juego")
                juego_activo = False

            if self.jugar_de_nuevo():
                print("Volvemos a jugar.")
            else:
                print(f"Adios {nombre}. ¡¡¡Vuelve pronto!!!")
                break


juego = Bingo()
print(juego.jugar())
```

Otra opción sería:

```
class Bingo:
    def jugar(self):
        # ....

        self.iniciar_juego()
        while True:
            j = input("¿Quieres volver a jugar? Responde si/no: ")
            while True:
                if (j == "si"):
                    print("Volvemos a jugar.")
                    self.iniciar_juego()
                    break
                elif (j == "no"):
                    print(f"Adios {nombre}. ¡¡¡Vuelve pronto!!!")
                    break
                else:
                    j = input("Por favor, introduce un valor válido: ")

    def iniciar_juego(self):
        juego_activo = True
        while juego_activo:
            print("Jugando")
            print("Terminó el juego")
            juego_activo = False


juego = Bingo()
print(juego.jugar())
```

Te recomiendo seguir las [guías de estilo par código Python definidas en PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Por convención los métodos y funciones se nombran en minúscula y con subrayado para separar palabras.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya funciona!